# JSF el expression with "and" returns always false

Tags: jsf, operators, el

I wrote el jsf expression with `and` operator but it returns false even if both are true.

`#{not empty scope.jobContext}` is true

`#{not empty scope.manager}` is true

`#{not empty scope.jobContext and not empty scope.manager}` is false.

I don't know why. What could be wrong?

Comment: It works for me, how are you checking if it is true or not?

Comment: I just write it in a div.